# Serialize() not using .XmlSerializers.dll produced with Sgen

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, xml-serialization, sgen

I have a sgen step in my .NET 3.5 library, producing a correct XYZ.XmlSerializers.dll in the output directory.
Still having poor serialization performance, I discovered that .NET was still invoking a csc at runtime. Using process monitor, I saw that .NET was searching for a dll named "XYZ.XmlSerializers.-1378521009.dll".

Why is there a '-1378521009' in the filename ? How to tell .NET to use the 'normal' DLL produced by sgen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poking around a bit with Reflector, this seems to happen when you use the XmlSerializer(Type, string) constructor, specifying a custom namespace.  Try using the XmlSerializer(Type) constructor instead.