# SOAP API C# response very slowly (30 times more than calling in Postman)

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, amadeus

I am trying to figure out why the first WCF call after client application start takes much more time comparing to second one.

For example below,

First times:

- In postman, it responses within 200ms
- In console app, it response at least 6000ms (200ms x30)

Next times:

- In postman, it responses within 200ms
- In console app, it responses within 200ms

For another example, if it responses 1s in postman, then it responses 30s in console app.

I'm using framework .Net 4.7.2 (64-bit)

```
static void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Air_FlightInfo body = new Air_FlightInfo();
            body.generalFlightInfo = new Air_FlightInfoGeneralFlightInfo();
            body.generalFlightInfo.companyDetails = new Air_FlightInfoGeneralFlightInfoCompanyDetails();
            body.generalFlightInfo.companyDetails.marketingCompany = "NH";
            body.generalFlightInfo.companyDetails.operatingCompany = "VN";
            body.generalFlightInfo.flightIdentification = new Air_FlightInfoGeneralFlightInfoFlightIdentification();
            body.generalFlightInfo.flightIdentification.flightNumber = "9727";

            string typeObject = body.GetType().ToString();
            try
            {
                var mHostedUser = new AMA_SecurityHostedUser();
                mHostedUser.UserID = new AMA_SecurityHostedUserUserID();
                mHostedUser.UserID.AgentDutyCode = AppSetting.AgentDutyCode;
                mHostedUser.UserID.POS_Type = AppSetting.POS_Type;
                mHostedUser.UserID.PseudoCityCode = AppSetting.PseudoCityCode;
                mHostedUser.UserID.RequestorType = AppSetting.RequestorType;
                mHostedUser.UserID.RequestorID = new UniqueID_Type();
                mHostedUser.UserID.RequestorID.CompanyName = new CompanyNameType();
                mHostedUser.UserID.RequestorID.CompanyName.Value = AppSetting.CompanyName;

                var session = new Session();
                session.TransactionStatusCode = "Start";

                var link = new TransactionFlowLinkType();
                link.Consumer = new ConsumerType();
                link.Consumer.UniqueID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

                var client = new AmadeusWebServicesPTClient("AmadeusWebServicesPort");

                ClientBase<AmadeusWebServicesPT> mClient = client;
                Uri uri = mClient.Endpoint.Address.Uri;
                string newUri = uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Host + "/" + "NameAccessPoint";
                EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(newUri);
                mClient.Endpoint.Address = address;

                var reply = client.Air_FlightInfo(ref session, ref link, mHostedUser, body);
                Console.WriteLine(reply);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Reduce SOAP API response time

Comment: Could be `XmlSerializer` code generation startup costs, see [XmlSerializer - the first deserialization is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45871161).  Are you using .NET Framework or .NET Core?  32-bit or 64-bit?  If Framework, try enabling compile-time [SGen.exe serializer assembly generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-serializer-generator-tool-sgen-exe).  See also [Generating an Xml Serialization assembly as part of my build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134224).

Comment: I will try this. But I think the problem is not at XmlSerializer code generation startup. Because I generate API by adding "Service Reference" in Visual Studio, point to file .wsdl, and it automatically generates API while coding.
I use .NET 4.7.2 (64-bit)

Comment: In client-side the first call takes more time because the channelfactory need to instantiate and prepare for communication and this will cost time. The channelfactory caching and reuse can reduce part of the time. [This case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43f89088-546b-46b0-adf8-214deb1741bd/how-to-cache-channelfactory?forum=wcf) may be helpful to you.